# Generating Boolean Searches Against an Array of Sentences to Group Results into n Results or Fewer

Tags: algorithm, search, full-text-search

I feel this is a strange one. It comes from nowhere specific but it's a problem I've started trying to solve and now just want to know the answer or at least a starting place.

- I have an array of x number of sentences,
- I have a count of how many sentences each word appears in,
- I have a count of how many sentences each word appears in with every other word,
- I can search for a sentence using typical case insensitive boolean search clauses (AND +/- Word)

My data structure looks like this:

```
{ words: [{ word: '', count: x, concurrentWords: [{ word: '', count: x }] }] }
```

**I need to generate an array of searches which will group the sentences into arrays of n size or less.**

I don't know if it's even possible to do this in a predictable way so approximations are cool. The solution doesn't have to use the fact that I have my array of words and their counts. I'm doing this in JavaScript, not that that should matter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide an example, This looks interesting to me

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker I'd love to, [here's a pastebin of some test data](http://pastebin.com/uRmLzfDy) in JSON format because that seemed to make the most sense, not that my code gets its input like that, it parses a big blob of text and splits it by line. The actual data can but upwards off 2000 items but there is a lot of crossover with the words used.

Comment: Got it, one more thing: what does concurrentWords mean? in your context

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker it is a (sortof) hashtable of each word that each item in the output array appears in a sentence with, with the value being the number of times they occur together. E.g The word "unique" appears with the words "want", "keep", "count", "low", "sentence", "turtle", "list" once, and the words "the", "word" and "this" twice. Thanks for taking the time to think about this.

Comment: The first thing i am thinking of is using RegEx, did you try something with it?

Comment: @Alundrathedreamwalker Honestly not sure how this problem could be solved by Regular Expressions. Not to underestimate the power of RegEx or anything but I was expecting something that would be mapping the data in a specific way and some maths to pinpoint the answer. What were you thinking with Regular Expressions that could work out something probably statistical which could work out groups of search results into chunks of n size?

Comment: Would a C# program be good for implementation.? I am interested and I can sketch out something